# Using flutter to control a squid proxy

Tags: flutter, proxy, squid

I am currently working on my first solo project with Flutter and I'd like to try and make an application that allows parents mostly, control what kind of things that their childrens devices can look at via online. So essentially, I want to write a flutter application that can control the internet traffic of a proxy server.

I've been doing some research on the topic and not a lot has come back to me, making it seem like it's impossible to do so.

Any resources on the matter/pointers in the right direction of how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated :)

I've tried researching about the topic but nothing concrete has come back, doens't seem like it's possible at all to do this using flutter.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Seeking recommendations for books, tutorials etc. is considered offtopic. So you will most likely not receive many answers.

Comment: Hey ye, kinda saw traffic was a bit slow lol, can you tell me if what I’m trying to do is even possible? If you’re educated on the topic of course :)